# Clojure, re-graph fetched data from graphql successfully, but callback didn't activate

Tags: clojure, graphql, clojurescript, re-frame, graphqlclient

So I use re-graph version 0.1.11 and I try fetching data from the endpoint. After fetching data, I checked network tab in the browser and I found the expected data after that it should activate my callback function, but it doesn't seem to work (but sometimes it works and after refreshing the page a few times it doesn't work again). Here is the code.

```
;; how I init re-graph
(rf/dispatch [::re-graph/init
              ::conf/graphql-client-name
              {:ws-url url
               :http-url url
               :ws-reconnect-timeout 500
               :resume-subscriptions? true}])

(re-frame.core/reg-event-fx
 ::fetch-expected-data
 (fn [cofx event]
   (let [app-db (:db cofx)
         some-params (-> event second (cljs.core/js->clj :keywordize-keys true))
         token (-> app-db (lens/get-in (auth-db/lens-token :group-level-x)))]
     (re-frame.core/dispatch
      [:re-graph.core/query
       ::conf/graphql-client-name
       "query findExpectedData($query: FetchExpectedDataInput!, $token: String!) {
         findExpectedData(query: $query, token: $token){
           value1
           value2
           ...
         }
       }"
       {:query some-params
        :token token}
       ;; this is where the problem occurs
       ;; even though i found the data in the network tab, but
       ;; this callback doesn't seem to work (sometimes it works sometimes it doens't)
       [::fetched-data-completed]]))))

(re-frame.core/reg-event-fx
 ::fetched-data-completed
 (fn [cofx [_ {:keys [data errors] :as payload}]]
   (let [app-db (:db cofx)
         error-message (-> errors :errors first :message)]
     (if (or (nil? errors) (empty? errors))
       (do (bla bla when success))
       (pr error-message)))))
```

I'm stuck with this problem for a few months. maybe because I fetch a lot of data at the same time? or could be something else anyone knows?. By the way the actual code I use defmacro, but it works the same way as the above code.

Answer (score 3):

So I managed to find the answer to my own question. It seems like app-db has not been initialized properly so I fixed that problem and everything works fine. hope it helps someone who struggle with this problem.